# Differentiability and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

1. If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$, is it necessary that $f$ uniformly continuous on an open interval $(-a,a)$?
2. If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and is bounded, is $f'$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1., notice that the derivative of $f$ is bounded ; the interval $[-a-1,a+1]$ is compact, hence since $f$ is continuously differentiable, the derivative is continuous, thus bounded. Given $x$ and $y$, there exists $\zeta$ between them such that 
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\zeta)||x-y|
$$
and you can bound $|f'(\zeta)|$ by its maximum on $[-a-1,a+1]$.

For 2., just choose a function which "oscillates too much at infinity", so that this bound on $|f'(\zeta)|$ breaks globally (it cannot break locally, because this is 1.). Boundedness of the function does not help, it's the boundedness of the derivative which does, as in 1.

As an example, take $f(x) = \sin(x^2)$ ; its derivative is $2x \cos(x^2)$, which is not uniformly continuous on the real line ; this is because the derivative grows arbitrarily large in absolute value, so you can find arbitrarily close points whose distance is $2$ for example. I leave it up to you to use the properties of the sine function to find them.

Hope that helps,